# Display Selected Data from database in drop down list

Tags: java, database, servlets, drop-down-menu, foreach

My goal is to selected data in database and display in drop down list.

For example, see the image below show that fbMenuId = M001 (Lasagne).

[image: database1]

So at dropdownlist M001 option will be selected. I also need display OTHER MENU like M002,M003,M004,M005,M006 and M007. For example, see the image below

[image: database]

However, my outcome is

[image: ddl]

Below are my codes

```
<select class="form-control" name="menu" id="menu">
                                            <option value="${order.fbMenuId}" selected>${order.fbMenuName}</option>
                                            <c:forEach var="menu" items="${menu}">
                                                <option value="${menu.fbMenuId}">${menu.fbMenuName}</option>
                                            </c:forEach>

</select>
```

I am able to display M001 Lasagne. However, there are 2 Lasagne which I do not want. Anyone please help me. Help will be appreciate. Thanks in advance!

Below are codes for servlet and data access object.

**Servlet**

```
OrderDAO dao = new OrderDAO();
request.setAttribute("order", dao.getOrder(fbOrderId));
request.setAttribute("menu", dao.getMenu(restaurant));
```

**OrderDAO**

```
public OrderBean getOrder(Integer fbOrderId) {

            OrderBean ob = new OrderBean();
            try {
                currentCon = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
                Statement statement = currentCon.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT fborders.fbMenuId, fbMenuName FROM fborders INNER JOIN fbmenu ON fborders.fbMenuId = fbmenu.fbMenuId WHERE fbOrderId='"+ fbOrderId + "'");

                while (rs.next()) {
                    ob.setFbMenuId(rs.getString("fbMenuId"));
                    ob.setFbMenuName(rs.getString("fbMenuName"));
                }

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return ob;
        }



public ArrayList getMenu(String restaurant) {

        ArrayList<OrderBean> am = new ArrayList<OrderBean>();
        try {
            currentCon = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
            Statement statement = currentCon.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = statement
                    .executeQuery("SELECT fbMenuId, fbMenuName FROM fbmenu WHERE fbRestaurantId='"
                            + restaurant + "'");

            while (rs.next()) {
                OrderBean ob = new OrderBean();
                ob.setFbMenuId(rs.getString("fbMenuId"));
                ob.setFbMenuName(rs.getString("fbMenuName"));
                am.add(ob);
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return am;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select class="form-control" name="menu" id="menu">
    <c:forEach var="menu" items="${menu}">
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${menu.fbMenuId == order.fbMenuId}">
                <option value="${order.fbMenuId}" selected>${order.fbMenuName}</option> 
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <option value="${menu.fbMenuId}">${menu.fbMenuName} </option>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding, you are showing the selected value twice. one time by appending

```
  <option value="${order.fbMenuId}" selected>${order.fbMenuName}</option>
```

and another time by iterating the list. Instead of this populate all the values in the dropdown and set the required value as selected. Just write simple condition like the following.

```
   <select class="form-control" name="menu" id="menu">         
      <c:forEach var="menu" items="${menu}">
          <option value="${menu.fbMenuId}">${menu.fbMenuName} 
          <c:if test="${menu.fbMenuId == order.fbMenuId}">
           selected
           </c:if>
          </option>
      </c:forEach>
   </select>
```

Comment: Thanks! However, from your code, <option value="${menu.fbMenuId}">${menu.fbMenuName} it still show the selected value. Which means, if selected is fish and chips. Menu still show fish and chips, thus fish and chips appear twice. I do not want to appear twice. One will do. <c:if test="${menu.fbMenuId == order.fbMenuId}"> Is there a way to make it not visible?

Comment: Sorry, Please remove the **`<option value="${order.fbMenuId}" selected>${order.fbMenuName}</option>`** line and try. I just edited my answer please find it.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. However. There is still a problem. It does not show the selected value. I believe this code is wrong. <c:if test="${menu.fbMenuId == order.fbMenuId}">
           selected
           </c:if> This code appears "Fish & Chips selected"

Comment: Ok I'm just giving an idea how to overcome your problem. Please try for correct JSTL syntax as I'm not good at it.